# Unable to change the refresh rate to 60hz with xrandr

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, xrandr

My monitor supports 1920×1080 @ 60hz (LG W2486L) and graphic card (GeForce 9400 GT)
using Ubuntu 12.04.

When I type `xrandr -q` I get this:

```
xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080      50.0* 
1920x1080_59.90   59.9  
1920x1080_60.00   60.0
```

Right now the refresh rate is on 50 and hurt my eyes real bad.
So I'm trying to change it to 60hz:

```
xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

What I can do? I tried

```
gtf 1920 1080 60.0

# 1920x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 172.80 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  172.51  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19

xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Someone have the solution for this? I can't work on the PC like that, 50Hz is very low and can't look at the screen more than 5 mins.

Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you had `clk 172.51` instead of `172.8` as was calculated from GTF in your xrandr command?

Comment: i don't know...

Comment: Just a commnent... Don't understand why this EOL Ubuntu 12.04 abandoned question got bumped to the home page when OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years (2 days after this question was posted) and therefore unlikely to confirm or deny any answers posted. Who exactly is the `community` that `bumped to home page` 10 minutes ago?

Comment: January 15, 2018 and this question from 2013 just got bumped by the robot again.

Comment: Aug 8, 2019 and robot bumped to home page again...

Answer (score 1):

Your xrandr -q output shows that you have 1920x1080_59.90 resolution available

You can use this to set the new resolution

```
xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080_59.90
```

Also, if you are creating newmode using

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_59.90"  172.51  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

You also need to add this mode using

```
xrandr --addmode default 1920x1080_59.90
```

And then set the new resolution using

```
xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080_59.90
```

Comment: well after i reboot the pc, xrandr -q results change to:
  1920x1080      50.0* 

   1680x1050      51.0     52.0  
   1600x1024      53.0  
   1440x900       54.0  
and it make no sense, i should have 1920x1080 with 60hz

Comment: you have to write scripts to make it persistent on reboot

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: put all the codes given above in a file and create a script,

For example :Create xrandr.sh

#!/bin/bash

    xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_59.90"  172.51  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync

    xrandr --addmode default 1920x1080_59.90
    
    xrandr --output default --mode 1920x1080_59.90

Then make this script to autorun on startup

Comment: You can even add this line    Modeline "1920x1080_59.90"  172.51  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync     in the Monitor section of xorg.conf file in /etc/X11