# add resolution to ATI card - 16.04

Tags: drivers, dell, display-resolution, xrandr, amd-graphics

my computer is dell Inspirion One 
http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-one-2205-athlon-ii-x2-240e-2-8-ghz-4-gb-500-gb-led-21-5/specs/

```
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1400/370x1050/278+0+0  default
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ 


kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci |grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]
```

target resolution is 1920 x 1080

```
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list
bcmwl-kernel-source
amd64-microcode
```

i try in this way

```
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync%
xrandr: unrecognized option '-hsync'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: unrecognized option '-hsync'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 +vsync%
xrandr: unrecognized option '+vsync%'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
kbywalec@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120%
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Update1 
as a root i have

```
root@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:/home/kbywalec# xrandr --newmode 1920x1080_60 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
root@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:
```

UPDATE 2

i have only this information

```
xrandr -q 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1400 x 1050, current 1400 x 1050, maximum 1400 x 1050
default connected primary 1400x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1400x1050     77.00*
```

i try with 50

```
root@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:/home/kbywalec# xrandr --newmode 1920x1080_50 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
root@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:/home/kbywalec#
```

UPDATE 3 
I test same situation on next laptop (sony vaio)

i write second about it here [nvidia driver in 16.04 - GT216M - sony vaio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770220/nvidia-driver-in-16-04-gt216m-sony-vaio)

```
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ lspci |grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] (rev a2)


grek@lapop-vaio:~$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync%
xrandr: unrecognized option '-hsync'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 +vsync%
xrandr: unrecognized option '+vsync%'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120%
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr: failed to parse '1920x1080_60.00' as a mode specification
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --help
usage: xrandr [options]
  where options are:
  --display <display> or -d <display>
  --help
  -o <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
            or --orientation <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
  -q        or --query
  -s <size>/<width>x<height> or --size <size>/<width>x<height>
  -r <rate> or --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
  -v        or --version
  -x        (reflect in x)
  -y        (reflect in y)
  --screen <screen>
  --verbose
  --current
  --dryrun
  --nograb
  --prop or --properties
  --fb <width>x<height>
  --fbmm <width>x<height>
  --dpi <dpi>/<output>
  --output <output>
      --auto
      --mode <mode>
      --preferred
      --pos <x>x<y>
      --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
      --reflect normal,x,y,xy
      --rotate normal,inverted,left,right
      --left-of <output>
      --right-of <output>
      --above <output>
      --below <output>
      --same-as <output>
      --set <property> <value>
      --scale <x>x<y>
      --scale-from <w>x<h>
      --transform <a>,<b>,<c>,<d>,<e>,<f>,<g>,<h>,<i>
      --off
      --crtc <crtc>
      --panning <w>x<h>[+<x>+<y>[/<track:w>x<h>+<x>+<y>[/<border:l>/<t>/<r>/<b>]]]
      --gamma <r>:<g>:<b>
      --brightness <value>
      --primary
  --noprimary
  --newmode <name> <clock MHz>
            <hdisp> <hsync-start> <hsync-end> <htotal>
            <vdisp> <vsync-start> <vsync-end> <vtotal>
            [flags...]
            Valid flags: +HSync -HSync +VSync -VSync
                         +CSync -CSync CSync Interlace DoubleScan
  --rmmode <name>
  --addmode <output> <name>
  --delmode <output> <name>
  --listproviders
  --setprovideroutputsource <prov-xid> <source-xid>
  --setprovideroffloadsink <prov-xid> <sink-xid>
  --listmonitors
  --listactivemonitors
  --setmonitor <name> {auto|<w>/<mmw>x<h>/<mmh>+<x>+<y>} {none|<output>,<output>,...}
  --delmonitor <name>

grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hync +vsync%
xrandr: unrecognized option '-hync'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -HSync +VSync%
xrandr: unrecognized option '-HSync'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
grek@lapop-vaio:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode %Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120%
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

both laptops was upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 
(i preffers open source drivers because it support second USB graphics card )
Where can by a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have the xrandr syntax wrong and you don't need to run it sudo either.

first introduce the mode to xrandr

```
xrandr --newmode 1920x1080_60 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then assign it to the relevant output (e.g. hdmi, dp1 , vga)

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080_60
```

Then make the output use the new resolution

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080_60
```

This is quite a standard resolution so i'm suprised you actually need to do this, it would suggest that your monitor isn't properly advertising its  capabilities or your graphics card has a less optimal driver.

Comment: i switch to root but still have : root@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:/home/kbywalec# xrandr --newmode 1920x1080_60 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
root@compaq-Presario-CQ60-Notebook-PC:

Comment: this actually looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/265939/unable-to-change-the-refresh-rate-to-60hz-with-xrandr?rq=1 which suggests the monitor might not be able to do 60hz but could manage 59hz . 

try running xrandr -q  to see what your display says it can support

Comment: i add code, still dont work

Comment: anything in your Xorg logs ?

Comment: here is xorg.log http://pastebin.com/ZRqRTSGr i also update post - add simmilar situation in other laptop